# Php url parsing and editing

Tags: php, http, url

I searched "the whole" stackoverflow but didn't find a decent answer that works for me. I need to change the host of a url in php.

> This url: http://example123.com/query?t=de&p=9372&pl=bb02799a&cat=&sz=400x320&scdid=e7311763324c781cff2d3bc55b2d83327aba111f2db79d0682860162c8a13c24&rnd=29137126
>
> To This: http://example456.com/test?t=de&p=9372&pl=bb02799a&cat=&sz=400x320&scdid=e7311763324c781cff2d3bc55b2d83327aba111f2db79d0682860162c8a13c24&rnd=29137126

I only need to change the domain and the path or file, so far I've got this:

```
$originalurl = http://example123.com/query?t=de&p=9372&pl=bb02799a&cat=&sz=400....
$parts = parse_url($originalurl);
$parts['host'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$parts['path'] = '/test';
$modifiedurl = http_build_query($parts);
print_r(urldecode($modifiedurl));
```

but it echos

> scheme=http&host=localhost&path=/test&query=t=de&p=9372&pl=bb02799a&cat=&sz=400...

Please I don't want to use some strpos or something like that as I need it to be variable.
Thanks ;)

Comment: because `http_build_query()` builds a query (funnily enough), and not a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://example123.com/query?t=de&p=9372&pl=bb02799a&cat=&sz=400x320&scdid=e7311763324c781cff2d3bc55b2d83327aba111f2db79d0682860162c8a13c24&rnd=29137126';
$query = parse_url($url)['query'];

$newUrl = 'http://www.younewdomain.com/path?' . $query;
```

Comment: Thank you that's almost exactly waht I want but this gets me the url right but the query gets a new line how can I fix this Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do some concatenating manually. This works:

```
$originalurl = "http://example123.com/query?t=de&p=9372";
$parts = parse_url($originalurl);
$new_path = '/test';
$modifiedurl = $parts['scheme'] . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $new_path . (isset($parts['query']) ? "?".$parts['query']:"");
print_r($modifiedurl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a different approach:

```
$url = "http://example123.com/query?t=de&p=9372&pl=bb02799a&cat=&sz=400x320&scdid=e7311763324c781cff2d3bc55b2d83327aba111f2db79d0682860162c8a13c24&rnd=29137126";
$new_host = "http://newhost.com/blab";

//explode at ? so you get the query
$split = explode("?",$url,2);

//build new url
$new_url = $new_host."?".$split[1];

//finish
echo $new_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reverse function of parse_url() should be [http_build_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php), have you tried with it?

Comment: http_build_url() is not a standard function of PHP, its in the PECL extension

Comment: `http_build_url` may be the exact thing he want's but it's not always available => `(PECL pecl_http >= 0.21.0)`

Comment: it's available here though, https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url, easy to get through composer

Comment: easy enough, but a little much for one function